# MySQL table keeps corrupting, need a simple fail over solution?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, corruption

One of my clients servers recently crashed at the planet, we got an automatic email from them that they had to do a hard reboot. Since then mysqld stops running occasionally and then shopping cart stopped letting users add products to their cart. I found it was a corrupted table storing session data. This table has kept crashing every few days and after tech support at the planet looked into the server they upgraded the bios memory and are planning to replace the entire server as there was some hardware issues.

All the crashes seem to have affected the shopping cart mainly the sessions table. What is a simple solution to fail over to another database if a table becomes corrupted? I've searched the site and saw some questions and answers pointing to these three sites

http://www.codership.com/
http://mysql-mmm.org/
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-solutions-switch.html

Would replicating help any if a table is corrupted in one database wouldn't copying it just copy the bad table data? So I need some way to monitor the tables and if any become corrupted redirect traffic or take that db offline until its fixed. Any help is appreciated, the simpler the solution the better

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about incremental backups of your raw datafiles ?